# Why do I get some dependency errors when adding node packages and compile with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm quite new to webpack but enjoying it. One thing that seems to pop up are dependency errors from other packages. For example, I just added @vimeo/player to a project and when my project compiled in webpack it threw this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

This dependency was not found in node_modules:

* jquery
```

I see in the vimeo package.json they've got jQuery as a dev dependancy however I'm not trying to build their package, simply use their already compiled js within their dist. Can anyone shed some light on why I keep running into this?

Comment: use `npm install jquery --save`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vimeo compiled js dependencies are pointing to node_modules.

Ex: 
   `import jquery from 'jquery';`

if there is no jquery module in node_module it throws an error.

Similarly in vimeo compiled js is using dependencies. you have to install those dependencies.

because webpack creates all js files as modules.

so use `npm install jquery -save`

Comment: Alright, I see... so even if  I want to use their already compiled js, I still have to go into their project and run npm install if I run into a dependancy issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using (probably you have):

```
import vimeo from 'vimeo';
```

use dist build as you wanted:

```
import vimeo from 'vimeo/dist/player'; // or player.min
```